# Android Navigation Component Backstack on self call

Tags: android, android-navigation

I am using the Android Navigation Component to handle the fragments.

I have Fragment A, B, C and E which can all open Fragment D (with a little different data).

On Fragment D you can then go either back or open another Fragment D with different data.

The user may click A->D->D->D->D->D and then back.

Is there a simple way to get back directly to A (or B, C, E whatever was the starting point) from D without going back all D calls?

I was hoping I could set parameters on the action arrows, but did not find any setting which worked.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's exactly what the "Single Top" option does: only allows a single copy of that destination on the top of the back stack.

```
<action android:id="@+id/action_nav_detail_self"
    app:destination="@id/nav_detail"
    app:launchSingleTop="true"/>
```

Comment: While this sounds like the perfect solution, setting this parameter does not have any effect at all. User still has to go back 5 times on D. I use findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_detail, args) to navigate.

Comment: Indeed, I just needed to change the call to findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_detail_self, args).

Comment: Yeah, you have to use the action's ID to trigger the action. Glad you were able to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky way for navigating directly from D to A

override onBackpressed in your parent activity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_fragment)
                .getCurrentDestination().getId() == (id of D)) {
            NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

        navController.navigate(R.id.action_D_to_A);

        }
       else
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: This would require me to keep track of the starting fragment, because I do not want to go back to A all the time. This is not the intention of using the Navigation Component.

Answer (score 0):

Your popUpTo is going back to the DetailFragment and then popping it because of the inclusive.

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_nav_detail_self"
    app:destination="@id/nav_detail"
    app:popUpTo="@id/nav_detail"
    app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
```